# Salesforce Case Feed - Creating/Adding Custom Tools

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

Within the console on a feed layout, we can add tools to the page such as the inline article tool. The feed view setting options with the page layout edit suggest (i.e. help text says "select the tools to make available in the center column of the page") that more than one tool can be created using code and added to the page layout (i.e. within the feed directly below the publisher actions but above the feed items). There is even a multi-select control to move the tools from available to selected, but...

I cannot find any documentation that discusses how to create the tools or how to make them available within the setup menu. Can you provide any insight to if this is possible and if so how to do it?

See example screens below...

thanks
jf

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please chk it - https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/10/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_case_interaction_setup_cheatsheet.pdf

Hope it helps.